# SQL query error using to_char

Tags: php, sql, oracle

The last line of my query will not run without "not a valid month" error. I am trying to convert a start time in GMT to local time using an offset in one of the columns, then compare this to a date I have in a variable. It works without using the to_char and offset.

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
    AND to_char(CT.START_GMT + K.OFFSET/1440,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') >=     TO_DATE('$From_Date', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: `TO_DATE('$From_Date', 'mm/dd/yyyy')` .. you have what is put inside `$fromdate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND CT.START_GMT + K.OFFSET/1440 >=     TO_DATE('$From_Date', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

You don't need a `TO_CHAR()` conversion.. if `CT.START_GMT` is a `DATE`

If `CT.START_GMT` is *not* `DATE/TIMESTAMP` , then you need to do `TO_DATE()` with the right format.